# htacccess, зеркало чтобы оставить старый URL

Tags: .htaccess

Запутался окончательно, требуется помощь зала. :)

Есть сайт `sub.site.org`. Нужно чтобы при заходе на него открылся контент сайта
`newsite.com/index.php?id=1`, но при этом чтобы посетителю сайта `sub.site.org` не поменялся URL.

Что нужно прописать в `.htaccess` сайта `sub.site.org`?

Заранее спасибо!